# Angular 5 binding CSS classes: class, [class.foo], [ngClass]

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular5

So I've been using Angular 5 for quite some time. And this question came to my mind: **what is the best way to bind CSS classes to an element**.

1. ## `class="{{ foo }}"`

   This way of binding gives us the opportunity to create CSS class name in `.ts` file, place the logic in `.ts` file, then use this given CSS class in HTML like this: `{{ foo }}`.

Example:

```
// foo.component.ts
...
export class FooComponent {
  someBool = true;
  foo = someBool ? 'error' : 'success'; // dummy logic
}
...

// foo.component.html
...
<div class="{{ foo }}"></div>
...
```

2. ## `[class.error]="foo"`

   This way lets us use `.ts` variable to toggle specific CSS class

Example:

```
// foo.component.ts
...
export class FooComponent {
  someBool = true;
  foo = someBool; // dummy logic
}
...

// foo.component.html
...
<div [class.error]="foo"></div>
...
```

3. ## `[ngClass]="{'error': foo, 'success': !foo}"`

   This one lets us add many CSS classes, imho it is the most readable one.

Example:

```
// foo.component.ts
...
export class FooComponent {
  someBool = true;
  foo = someBool; // dummy logic
}
...

// foo.component.html
...
<div [ngClass]="{'error': foo, 'success': !foo}"></div>
...
```

---

**So let me know what, in your opinion, is the best way to do CSS classes binding. I know, there might be other ways to do so - let me know about them.**

Comment: all of them have a different usage, none is best, it's based on requirement

Comment: Personally I prefer the last one too. As I always write templates in their own file, it seems cleaner and more obvious to write classes in the template as they're presentation, keeping logic separate in the class.

Comment: @Rakeschand tell me about the different usage

Comment: You seem to already know the different usage.